# Hide/Unhide html elements using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder if you can help me out on this code, I have a html page with three tables, I'm looking forward to show one of the three tables every 60 seconds in order, something like this: pseudo-code = start page show only the table number 1, 60 seconds later show only table number 2, 60 seconds later show only table 3, 60 seconds later again show only table 1 and so on (successively), I mean never stop doing this.
I have this eg.:

```
<body>
<h1>My testing</h1>
<table id="t1">
  <tr>
    <td> Table 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="t2">
  <tr>
    <td> Table 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="t3">
  <tr>
    <td> Table 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "t1" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );    
$( "t2" ).slideUp( 300 ).fadeIn( 400 );
$( "t3" ).slideUp( 300 ).fadeIn( 400 );
});
</script>
```

Please ignore the number and interval of times, I only need 60 seconds to occurs the action I mentioned above either using JQuery or Javascript...
I don't figure this process out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code may be it can help you -

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j13fLjs8/25/)

HTML CODE

```
<h1>Table Hide Show Code</h1>
<table id="t1" class="active">
    <tr>
        <td> Table 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="t2" class="removeActive">
    <tr>
        <td> Table 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="t3" class="removeActive">
    <tr>
        <td> Table 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS CODE

```
.active{
  display:block;
}
.removeActive{
  display:none;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
function toggleTable(){
    if($('#t1').hasClass('active')){
    $('table').removeClass('active').addClass('removeActive');
    $('#t2').removeClass('removeActive').addClass('active');
    }
  else if($('#t2').hasClass('active')){
    $('table').removeClass('active').addClass('removeActive');;
    $('#t3').removeClass('removeActive').addClass('active');
    }
  else if($('#t3').hasClass('active')){
    $('table').removeClass('active').addClass('removeActive');;
    $('#t1').removeClass('removeActive').addClass('active');
    }
};
var toggle = setInterval(function(){toggleTable()},60000);
```

Comment: If it works then please accept this answer by clicking on that checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `#` to each of your selectors.

```
$( "#t1" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );
$( "#t2" ).slideUp( 300 ).fadeIn( 400 );
$( "#t3" ).slideUp( 300 ).fadeIn( 400 );
```